# Regexp to replace words not between <a (whatever)> and (whatever) </a> tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regexp that match "myword" on any text that is not between anchor tags. Anything, including other tags like:

```
<strong>,</strong>,<span>,</span>,etc.
```

I have a regexp that works but not if there are any other tags between anchor tags.

This is my regexp:

```
(?!<a[^>]*?>)(\bmyword\b)(?![^<]*?</a>)
```

Example text:

```
<a href="xxxx">Lore ipsum <span> lore myword </span></a> Lore <b>myword</b>ipsum myword.
```

I need only the second and third "myword" mached. Not the first.

Can you help me please?

Comment: You might find a regex solution, but this is not a problem well suited for regular expressions. Since you are using JavaScript, can't you use the DOM objects to find a node containing the text you are looking for?

Comment: All the text (including anchor tags) is content in a paragraph tag.

Comment: @user3198610 it still remain  DOM objects

Comment: How can i exclude anchor tags content from the paragraph DOM object? The anchors are included on the paragraph.

Comment: What do you need to do with the matching elements later? Maybe there is a different approach we can do using jQuery.

Comment: I can't use jQuery, only pure javascript. The matching words must be replaced by other word.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JavaScript solution to your problem. You might need to modify a bit depending on the browser compatibility that your require (`textContent` is IE9+, you might need to use `innerHTML` if you support older browsers), but it should get you there.

Using the DOM objects is a more solid approach as HTML is not a regular language.

You mentioned in the comments that this is all wrapped in a `p`. I also added an `a` tag nested in another tag.

```
<p id="foo"><a href="xxxx">Lore ipsum <span> lore myword </span></a> Lore <b>myword</b>ipsum myword. <i><a href="xxxx">myword</a></i></p>
```

Javascript:

```
function replaceMyWord(parent) {
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < parent.childNodes.length; i += 1) {
        node = parent.childNodes[i];

        if (node.nodeName !== 'A') {
            if (node.childNodes.length > 0) {
                replaceMyWord(node);
            } else {
                node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(/myword/g, 'replacement');
            }
        }
    }
}

replaceMyWord(document.getElementById('foo'));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fSL5j/)

Comment: Rather than looping through child nodes, I might consider a query selector - either using some library like JQuery or Dojo, OR with the 'querySelectorAll' method, then the selector: "#foo, #foo span, #foo a". You may be able to import a small shim that would add support on IE7/8.

Comment: @Katana314 He mentioned that it had to be pure JS though, but yeah, there might be something to do with the `querySelectorAll`...

Comment: @Vache I have tested your code and it works well. But I can't replace the words by any other html, textContent only support plain text. For example to replace "myword" by "<b>otherword</b>"

Comment: Any solution using jQuery? Thanks.